# localhost and localhost:4200 CORS issue in angular

Tags: angular, api, iis, cors, localhost

I have tried all the possible ways found in we to solve the **CORS** issue in angular while runnig through **VS code** using **ng serve**

1. Implemented the prox.conf.json and then run

> ng serve --proxy config proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/`OSTNextService`": {

    "target": "https://localhost/OSTNextService",
    "secure": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
    "^/OSTNextService": ""
  },


"`changeOrigin": true`
  }
}
```

2. set the IIS header to specif domain. in my case **https://localhost:4200**
   [image]
3. setting the service global.asax file

   [image]

Nothing working for me and am getting error like

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://localhost/OSTNextService/OSTPortalService.svc/GetUserName'
>   from origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
>   must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

when i hosted the application in IIS and mapped the dist folder to it everything working fine. but evey time i changed the .ts file i need to build the application is almost double time waste. please help by advising what i am missing here.

Comment: is your local host running on secure protocol ?

Answer (score 0):

use "/OSTNextService" instead of "/`OSTNextService`" in proxy file. And if you use simply `"target": "https://localhost/"` you do not need `rewrite`,

also do not use a full url in your app, but a relative `/OSTNextService/OSTPortalService.svc/GetUserName`, then it will hit your proxy and forward to localhost:80/...

I do not think there is any need to tinker with IIS headers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer of Normunds: use relative paths, otherwise the proxy will not work.
But I saw just one thing (hopefully a typo). You're serving your application with: ng serve --proxy config proxy.conf.json, while it should be: ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json (mind the dash between proxy and config)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33572802)